# parsing a string using pointer pointing to a string without using strdup and strtok functions

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers, gps

I am writing a code in which i want to parse a incoming string(basically this is for embeddded project, but i want to test it first in C).The string can be a GPS output , basically a NMEA string.Even though i had done parsing using strdup and strtok function but i am, stucked up when i am doing parsing simply using a string and pointer pointing to that string.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{int i;
char inputstring[100]; //i assumed it to be input string, in this case enter by user.
char *ptr[12];

printf("Enter the string to be printed now.: \n");
scanf("%s",inputstring);

printf("the input string being received from the user is = \n %s \n", inputstring);

for(i=0;i<12;i++)   /*used this for loop to get first 12 characters from inputstring copied into ptr[i] */
{
ptr[i] = &inputstring[i];
}
printf("value of store is = %s \n",*ptr);
return 0;


}
```

but the ouput of this is whole inputstring rather then the first 12 characters.I dig this out further and find that *ptr when points to inputstring, its points to the inputstring[0]
 and will copy whole string in it rather then just copying first 12 characters.How can we limit this ?

Need help.I have a alternate way but need help to dig out this code of mine.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char *ptr[12];
```

is an array of 12 character pointers, but you seem to want it to be an array of 12 characters. Remove the asterisk:

```
char ptr[12];
```

and re-name it, since `ptr` is a lousy name:

```
char tmp[12];
```

Then make sure that you terminate it, and have room for the terminator:

```
char tmp[13];

strlcpy(tmp, inputstring, sizeof tmp);
```

Comment: thanks,it works.well we can ofcourse use strcpy also.And i came to know that if we are using a *ptr, ptr[0] will point to whole inputstring[] and thats why earlier i was getting whole input string copied to ptr.

Answer (score 1):

```
char ptr[12];
```

instead of

```
char *ptr[12];
```

`char ptr[12]`: is an array of characters with size = 12 elements of chars. the size of each element in the array is = the size of char (1 byte).

`char *ptr[12]`: is an array of pointers with size = 12  elements of pointers. the size of each element in the array is = the size of pointer (4 bytes for 32-bit systems and 8 bytes for 64-bit systems). each pointer in the array could point to a string (char array).

you should use the following code instead

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++)
{
ptr[i] = inputstring[i];
}
```

or more simple

```
memcpy(ptr, inputstring, 12);
```

and you have to add null charachter at the end of your `ptr` string before you print the `ptr` string.

So you have to add 1 element to the size of the `ptr` char array

```
char ptr[13];

memcpy(ptr, inputstring, 12);
ptr[12] = '\0';
printf("value of store is = %s \n",ptr);
```